# Origin of time or origin of space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, time, big-bang

Are there alternate theories or models that contradicts the idea that big bang is the origin of time ?

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative viewpoint, you could try reading "The End of Time" by J. Barbour. I don't know enough about the subject to judge the book, but I did find it interesting in his arguments about there being no such thing as time.

Comment: Your question got closed before i had a chance to answer, but see my answer to [How can something happen when time does not exist?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24018/how-can-something-happen-when-time-does-not-exist) where I discuss what it means to say time started at the Big Bang.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Thank you. That was a good validation of my uncanny curiosity that disagreed to accept that there was no time before big bang. The new truth for me is "Now that doesn't necessarily mean there was no time before the Big Bang, it just means we have no way of calculating it from General Relativity."

Comment: What prior research have you done? Have you tried googling? #1 & #2 in a search on your title are  http://www.nature.com/news/theoretical-physics-the-origins-of-space-and-time-1.13613  and http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/where-do-space-and-time-come-from-new-theory-offers-answers-if-only-physicists-can-figure-it-out/

Comment: @sammygerbil: Thanks. Your comments lead me to scientific american and flipping through pages & articles I found this http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-myth-of-the-beginning-of-time-2006-02/. Check it out. It's a good one.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any other scientific theory that proves that big bang is the origin of time ?

Here is a gross misunderstanding of what a scientific theory is. A scientific theory can never be proven. It is successful if it fits data and observations, then one says it is validated, and if its predictions are always validated. An invalid prediction requires drastic changes in the scientific theory.

> I read in several sources that winding back general relativity equations leads to t=0, origin of time.

Wrong summary. The equations used to model the data and observations for the universe we live in, the [Big Bang model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang), have a singularity at the origin , which we can assume as the beginning , at x=0,y=0,z=0,t=0 . The model has been successfully modified as new observations are made that did not agree with the simplistic singularity model, but it is the dominant cosmological model.

> However, it makes sense to hypothesize time as an eternal dimension and big bang merely created space in time and hence the origin of space time.

It cannot be a bang in three dimensions because the data contradicts it. The data show that everything in the cosmos is [moving away](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/hubble.html) from everything else. In a three dimensional explosion there is a center to the motion. The [raisin  bread](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/nave-html/Faithpathh/originu.html) analogy may help in visualizing this.

[Steady state models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_State_theory) have been proposed but have not been successful in describing the observations.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I did not do a good job at asking my question though. What intrigues me is that our current understanding of cosmos is based on an assumption that there was 'nothing' before big bang which is a little hard to relate to. And what i was trying to ask is if there any theory that explores the idea that there was time even before big bang.

Answer (score 0):

Studying big bang itself gives a lot of evidences to believe in it.however redshift ,given by Edwin Hubble , is one of the major theory that supports it by giving evidence of expanding universe.cosmic wave background is also a big point to support it.

Comment: Agreed. All of above does point to a core theory that a Big Bang occurred. However non of it is indicates that there was no time before this event. May be there was no space time but nothing to support the absence of time.

Comment: You cannot find any evidence that there was absence of time as there was absence of time .nothing could happen before the starting of time ,so what about finding any evidence before TIME.....and after all its a theory

Comment: To put it in the simplest form I can. Assume a time line starting from t=50000 BC to t=50o00 AD. On this time line at some time t=t0, America was discovered. Based on the current existence of America and all it's attributes we cannot deny the existence of time before the discovery. And it's a good practice to put things in comments unless you have a well researched answer.